# How to register celery tasks across apps/projects in Django?

Tags: django, celery, pycharm

How to I call a celery (app) task from the project level and vice versa.

I have a Django directory structure like:

```
- proj
     |_ celery.py
     |_ settings.py
- app
     |_ tasks.py
     |_ views.py
```

In settings.py I have a CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE var which refers to a shared_task in `app/tasks`.  This task is not listed in `celery inspect registered`.

Neither are tasks which *are* listed in the registry since they were defined in `proj/celery.py`, callable by functions in `apps/views.py`.

I've followed the instructions on the celery website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions in the shared_task decorator must be listed in the apps AppConfig.

Under `app/apps.py` import your task like so:

```
from .tasks import add
```

In `app/tasks.py` import shared_task like so:

```
from proj.celery import shared_task
```

In `proj/celery.py` import shared_task like so:

```
import celery
from celery import shared_task
```

Pycharm will complain about unused imports, however they are used, just not in the file pycharm is parsing.

Now when I start celery worker like:

```
python manage.py celeryd --loglevel=DEBUG &
```

rather than

```
celery -A pears worker --loglevel=info &
```

My tasks in `app/tasks.py` are registered and callable.

Comment: Your usage may vary, depending on what your celery "app.autodiscover_tasks" setting is.  This answer assumes you are using "lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS" and `INSTALLED_APPS=['app.apps.AppConfig',...]` which are the defaults at the time of writing.

Comment: I guess this is the best answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38836969/3061689