# Django Celery Received unregistered task of type 'appname.tasks.add'

Tags: python, django, celery

Following the documentation and the Demo Django project here https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/3.1/examples/django

**Project Structure**

```
piesup2
    |
    piesup2
    |  |__init__.py
    |  |celery.py
    |  |settings.py
    |  |urls.py
    reports
       |tasks.py
       |models.py
       |etc....
```

**My Code**

`piesup2/celery.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'piesup2.settings')

from django.conf import settings  # noqa

app = Celery('piesup2')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

`piesup2/__init__.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app  # noqa
```

`piesup2/reports/tasks.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

After starting Celery from the command line with:

```
celery -A piesup2 worker -l info
```

When I attempt to run a task from within my models.py file like this:

```
 def do_stuff(self):
    from reports.tasks import add
    number = add.delay(2, 2)
    print(number)
```

I get the following error:

> [2016-08-05 16:50:31,625: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered
>   task of type 'reports.tasks.add'. The message has been ignored and
>   discarded.
>
> Did you remember to import the module containing this task? Or maybe
>   you are using relative imports? Please see http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-names for
>   more information.
>
> The full contents of the message body was: {'callbacks': None,
>   'retries': 0, 'chord': None, 'errbacks': None, 'task':
>   'reports.tasks.add', 'args': [2, 2], 'timelimit': [None, None],
>   'kwargs': {}, 'id': 'b12eb387-cf8c-483d-b53e-f9ce0ad6b421', 'taskset':
>   None, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'utc': True} (258b) Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/jwe/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py",
>   line 456, in on_task_received
>       strategies[name](message, body, KeyError: 'reports.tasks.add'

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your django settings you need to add each module that has a celery task to CELERY_IMPORTS

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = (
    'reports.tasks',
    'some_app.some_module',
)
```

Comment: Thanks, you have saved me :)